# If $u$ is a measure and $u(E) = 0$ then $\int_X f\chi_E du = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\Sigma,u)$ is a measure space and $u(E) = 0$ and let $f$ be $u$-integrable. I am trying to show that $\int_X f\chi_E du = 0$ where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E$.

All I can do so far is see that $f\chi_E = 0$ almost everywhere.

How can I show that the integral is in fact $0$ everywhere.

Comment: The integral is a fixed value, it doesnt depend on anything, it is either 0 or not, it can't be 0 a.e.

Comment: What do you know about $f$?

Comment: That it is $u$-integrable.

Comment: Separate the integral into $\int_E+\int_{E^c}$. On the second summand $\chi_E=0$ so the function inside the integral $f\chi_E$ is zero, on the first you are integrating some function on a set $E$ with $u(E)=0$

Comment: How do you show that $\int_E f du$ = 0? I am not seeing it.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an integral? That is, in measure theory.

Comment: Yes, $\int_X f du = \int_X f^+ du - \int_X f^- du$

Comment: And what is the definition of $\int_X f^+ du$?

Comment: Its the supremum of  the integrals over simple functions less that $f^+$. Which will all give the value $0$ if $u(E) = 0$? And hence $\int_E f^+ dm = 0$ and so the whole integral is $0$? Is this the idea?

Comment: For $\int_E$: This integral is the limit of the integrals of simple functions on $E$. But any simple function on $E$ will be a linear combination of characteristic functions of measurable subset of $E$. The measures of any of those subsets is zero. The integral of those simple functions will be a sum like $\sum a_iu(E_i)$, with $E_i\subset E$ and $E_i$ measurable. All those $u(E_i)=0$. Since the integrals of the simple functions is zero, so is their limit.

Comment: I figured as much, was hoping we wouldnt have to go down the the simple functions! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you know, for instance, the monotone convergence theorem (or Beppo Levi), then you don't have to use an approximation by simple functions.